Google Access Token Error: Request had invalid authentication credentials. - Javascript
when running the default code to obtain an access token, I am getting the error:
{
  error: {
    code: 401,
    message: 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.',
    errors: [ [Object] ],
    status: 'UNAUTHENTICATED'
  }
}

from code (source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin):
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    // IdP data available using getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.customData.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });

I believe this is telling me that what I am using now is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in): 
However, I have not found any workaround code to generate the access token required to use Google API services. Does anyone have a solution to this problem / managed to access Google API services despite the deprecation with Javascript?
